# istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer showing "Pending" in AWS EKS

Tags: istio, amazon-eks, istio-sidecar

I have installed a **private EKS cluster** where subnets attached are private subnet. What my requirement is **"Private EKS with Istio installation"** and create multiple microservices and expose them within the vpc.
For exposing them within VPC, i expected the 'istio-ingressgateway' would create an internal ALB but it is showing "Pending"

```
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   1xx.x0x.xx.2xx     <pending>
```

My need is to install multiple microservice within in different port using "NodePort" and expose them via Gateway.

Request any help or view in this.

Thanks!

Comment: By definition a Private EKS cluster use Private VPC's, so it cant create loadbalancers exposed to the internet because it lacks public subnets

Comment: thanks for the taking time to comment!. my thought was if i get an internal ALB address then within vpc i can do routing traffic from differnt node ports, ex: <internalalb:nodeport of microservice1> like that. any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Oh, yes an internal load balancer you can, going to post the instrucitons, sec

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, can use ALB ingress controller and create an internal ingress object and add the annotation:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: "internal"
```

or create a LoadBalancer service that will create an ELB. Add these annotations to the service:

> `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal`: Used on the service to indicate that we want an internal ELB.

> `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-security-groups`: Used to specify the security groups to be added to ELB created. This replaces all other security groups previously assigned to the ELB.

For example,

[image]

Also, you need these tags in the VPC subnets:

```
Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
Value: 1
```

For your case, take option 2.

Comment: I understood your point. but my aim is to create the service as "NodePort" and the gateway of istio .i.e. the istio: ingressgateway use a loadbalancer so that i can access each microservices via <istio loadbalancer url : nodeport>. but when i look "kubectl get svc -n istio-system" i always getting loadbalancer as <pending> expected an internal alb address here

Comment: It is not a good idea to expose any kind of service as NodePort, only encouraged for testing purposes

Comment: But the problem here is, i have 10-12 microservices so if i deploy using service Loadbalancer then i need to create 10-12 ALB's right ? which is too costly

Comment: Well your first requirement was to have a internal LoadBalancer, if you do that with the service internal annotation you will indeed need one per service, in the case you use the internal alb ingress (example 1) you just need one ALB per namespace